# Is there an option to have Bower and NPM automatically update their packages in Visual Studio 2015 when their source-controlled .json files change?

Tags: json, visual-studio, tfs, npm, bower

Currently, when you Get Latest from source control, and the bower.json or package.json files have changed, you still need to open and make a minor change to the file and re-save it in order for VS to be aware of the change and execute NPM or bower and pull updates.  Ideally, it would detect the change and execute it immediately upon getting the latest .json files.  I can understand the case for *not* wanting this to be the default behavior, but without this, our entire dev team needs to be notified and perform the extra steps whenever a .json file change is checked in (fairly often).

Is there an environment setting in VS that impacts this, or a feasible workaround that anyone is aware of?

Comment: When you get latest from TFS, the solution version on your local computer should be the same as server version. Why do you need to modify the file locally? The server version os not the one you want to use?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain well.  Say my local bower.json lists version 1.0.0 of Library X.  Another developer updates our common, TFS-based project to use version 1.0.1, and then checks in bower.json.  When I get latest, my bower.json file now reflects Library X version 1.0.1, but Visual Studio will not trigger bower to get version 1.0.1 at that point.  I need to open that latest bower.json file and then save it in order to get VS to execute bower's update call itself.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such setting in VS IDE.

As you figured out that when you save any changes to the package.json or bower.json file, Visual Studio automatically install or restore all packages. However, the auto check is not triggered when you get file from TFS version control.

You can, however, create a licenser to license to the GettingEventHandler  event. Once the event is triggered, run the scripts to install the updates:
npm install -g bower-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
bower-check-updates -u
npm install